# TinyMce rails plugins error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, dragonfly-gem

I am trying to use TInyMCE. I want Image upload feature. So I am going to follow this tutorial: `http://serenetechnologies.ca/using-dragonfly-to-upload-images-to-rails-with-tinymce/`

When I used the CDN provided by TinyMCE. But when I use the following plugin as a gem `https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload`, it searches for it in the cdn and fails to find it. SO I thought of using a gem for tinymce.

So used `tinymce-rails` gem. Then I copied the plugins `advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,contextmenu,paste` to the assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins folder.

I also copied the modern skin and theme to similar locations.

and I am invoking tinyMCE using:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    "mode":"specific_textareas",
    "selector": ".tinymce-editor",
    'theme': 'modern',
    "toolbar":"insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image uploadimage",
    "plugins":"advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,contextmenu,paste,uploadimage",
    "width":810,
    "language":"en"
  })
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

I dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tinymce plugin list (using tinymce4!) needs to look like this (with brackets)

```
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
],
```

Comment: Weird. I copied the code by inspecting the generated tinymce js function. Anyway thanks :)